# Citrus framework: need example of correct usage of message selector for Java Test designer

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I my test I have to select one of the several message from the channel queue. So I have step like this:

```
http()
  .server(server_name)
  .receive()
  .post(eventService)
.selector("xpath://Envelope/Body/CreateMessageDrivenEventRequest/MessageHeader/CustomsData/TraderIdentifier=123456NA")
```

but selector doesn't select needed request from the channel queue. Can anybody share the example of correct xpath or other type of selector?

Thanks,
Olha

Evaluated request:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24012100">
                <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <addr:To xmlns:addr="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">address</addr:To>
        <addr:Action xmlns:addr="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">action</addr:Action>
        <addr:ReplyTo xmlns:addr="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <addr:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</addr:Address>
        </addr:ReplyTo>
        <addr:MessageID xmlns:addr="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:b23a690e-15fc-4ffa-8a7f-dd981ebb92ba-1a</addr:MessageID>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <CreateMessageDrivenEventRequest xmlns="xxx">
            <cct:MessageHeader xmlns:cct="yyy">
                <cct:TransactionId>792974800</cct:TransactionId>
                <cct:MessageId>18c9d974-3a1c-48ca-811f-a0787d9d2ee5</cct:MessageId>
                <cd:CustomsData xmlns:cd="zzz">
                    <cd:TraderIdentifier>123456NA</cd:TraderIdentifier>
                    <cd:MailboxCollectId>NA123456NA</cd:MailboxCollectId>
                    <cd:MessageVersion>1</cd:MessageVersion>
                    <cd:DocumentFormat>xml</cd:DocumentFormat>
                    <cd:InputIndicator>DTI</cd:InputIndicator>
                    <cd:DateReceived>20161125141127</cd:DateReceived>
                </cd:CustomsData>
            </cct:MessageHeader>
            <n:MRN xmlns:n="xxx">123456789</n:MRN>
            <n:Event xmlns:n="xxxx">
                <cct:Date xmlns:cct="xxxx">20170126160630</cct:Date>
                <cct:User xmlns:cct="xxxx">System</cct:User>
                <cct:Comments xmlns:cct="xxxx">Message sent to Trader (Carrier)</cct:Comments>
                <cct:StateCode xmlns:cct="xxxx">I012</cct:StateCode>
                <cct:EventCode xmlns:cct="xxxx">1234</cct:EventCode>
            </n:Event>
</CreateMessageDrivenEventRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`

Comment: For now found this solution:
`.selector("xpath:*[local-name()='TraderIdentifier']='123456NA'")`
The value should be in single quotes since during parsing into key and value it looses first and last symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is not using any XML namespaces but the message is doing so. The expression must refer to the element namespaces of both SOAP and your domain.

Something like this:
      `xpath://soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns:CreateMessageDrivenEventRequest/ns:MessageHeader/ns:CustomsData/ns:TraderIdentifier=123456NA`

In addition to that you need to declare namespace prefix and value in a global namespace context for instance:

```
<citrus:namespace-context>
  <citrus:namespace prefix="soap" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"/>
  <citrus:namespace prefix="ns" uri="xxx"/>
</citrus:namespace-context>
```